# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Tags: c#

I have table Name OtherEarningandDeduction  in SQL server and there are few columns

```
    columns         dataType  
1). Id              guid     as primary key.
2). SalaryHeadId    guid     as FK.
3). Month           varchar 
4). AcademicYearId  guid     as FK
5). .....
6). .....
7). .....
```

and I want to check whether the same record is present in the table or not so i was using Linq in asp.net. and restrict from inserting record for those record which are present in the table.

manager is object of entity.

```
OtherEarningandDeduction obj =new OtherEarningandDeduction();


var dublicateCheck=manager.OtherEarningandDeduction.where(x=>x.SalaryHeadId==obj && x.month==obj.month && x.AcademicYearId==obj.AcademicYearId).toList();
```

I am getting the error on the above line...

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only
>   primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

So plese help me...

Comment: Shouldn't the first condition in the Where be `x.SalaryHeadId == obj.SalaryHeadId` instead of `x.SalaryHeadId == obj`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think the problem is because you compare `x.SalaryHeadId` to `obj`, instead of `obj.SalaryHeadId`.

I would think that this would work:

```
var dublicateCheck=manager.OtherEarningandDeduction.where(x=>x.SalaryHeadId==obj.SalaryHeadId && x.Month==obj.Month && x.AcademicYearId==obj.AcademicYearId).toList();
```

In your code, you're trying to compare the `SalaryHeadId` property (field) of `x` to the instantiated object, not the instantiated object's `SalaryHeadId` property (field).  Hence the error message.